# Understanding what to include in a clustered index when you have a composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm relatively new to using SQL and I am trying to implement clustered and non-clustered indexes on my database to improve performance.

Most of my tables use composite keys which include a unique ID relating to a customer (UserId), a field that talks about each instance of the customer buying something(ActId) and other fields such as RefId (Referrals) and EventId (Events).

My question is, when creating a clustered index, would I just use the fields I use to create the composite key as the fields to use in the index?

An example;

I have a table that is comprised of UserId, ActId, RefId which are all used to create the composite key amongst other fields for dates, descriptions etc.

Would I just create a clustered index as such?;

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX C_U_table_name_UserId_ActId,RefId ON table_name(UserId ASC, ActID ASC, RefID ASC);
```

Tbl example;

```
UserId   int
ActId    int 
RefId    int 
DateofPurchase    datetime
TimeofPurchase    varchar(5)
Description     varchar(max)
ReasonPurchase    varchar(max)
```

Comment: You generally would be creating one or more indices to cater to a query or queries.  You should include your queries in the question so that we have some idea.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have created many non-clustered indexes for queries I know are repeated often, my issue is regarding the one Clustered index you can have per table. These are the only fields in this table that have a numeric value, I'll edit the question to include the table design and some queries that are generally used

Comment: The article [Choosing the Right Clustering Key](https://www.sqlconsulting.com/archives/choosing-the-right-clustering-key) gives some insight on choosing a clustering key. Perhaps the most pertinent quote is - *"The first thing to understand about best practices is that there aren’t any. There are always cases where the ‘best practice’ is not the best choice. A simple set of rules can’t possibly cover the multitude of complexities involved in most decisions regarding SQL Server."*

Comment: As a general rule, if those 3 fields uniquely identify a row, they are going to be a very strong candidate for your clustering key, however, this is not the case for every set of 3 columns that uniquely identify a row, it all depends on the nature of those 3 columns, and the use of the table

Comment: @GarethD They are the only columns that increment and have static values which is why I assumed they are the best candidates for most tables. I'll read through the article, I appreciate the response.

Comment: If the composite key uniquely identifies a row, perhaps it should be the primary key (or at least a unique index/constraint). As to whether the index should be clustered or not depends on your queries. Side note, tables have columns, not fields.